# integer combination

Tags: mathematical-optimization

i want write a module to find the integer combination for a multi variable fomula. For example

```
  8x + 9y <= 124
```

The module will return all possible positive integer for x and y.Eg. x=2, y=12.
It does not neccessary be exactly 124, could be any number less or equal to 124. Must be as close as posible to124 if no exact solution could be found.

I do not want to solve with brute force as the number of variable could be any...(5,10,100,...n)

Any algorithm could solve this?

Comment: Might be worth asking this on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by recasting your problem as an *integer programming* problem.

Rewrite your equation as a constraint.

`8x + 9y < = 124`  as

`8x + 9y + z = 124`

Notice that we have introduced a slack variable `z`. We want `z` to be as small as possible, so make the `objective function` to be `Minimize z` Any solver will try all possible integer values of x and y before incrementing z.

Your full IP will be:

```
Min z
8x + 9y + z = 124
x,y,z >=0 and Integer
```

Solve using any commercial or open-source LP/IP solver. (R's optim package is one possibility, Excel Solver will also do.)

If for any reason, you want `x` or `y` to be larger or smaller, you can control those as well with the `objective function co-efficients.`

More generally, `Min Cx x + Cy y + Cz z` and control the weights of cost parameters Cx Cy and Cz to suit your needs.

Hope that helps.